# What is the rate at which questions are typically upvoted?

Tags: discussion, statistics, data-explorer

Every now and then I get a stray upvote for an answer I answered months ago. Usually these are for the more prominent answers I've given. But most of the time, the upvotes I get are shortly after I answer a question.

This made me think, what is the rate at which upvotes are received? Is there a discernible pattern that applies to all answers such as, 70% of upvotes occur on the first day, 85% by the second day, etc.? Perhaps there is a trend but it needs to be limited to answers that get >10 upvotes.

I believe there is a database query system available for the stack exchange websites but I don't know how it works. Does someone know the answer or know how to obtain it?

Comment: You ask about questions in the title, about answers in the body of the post.

Comment: I meant answers in the title but I'm interested in question upvotes as well.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are currently $1104554$ upvotes on answers in the SEDE database. Of them,

- $60.70\%$ were cast within the first day of existence of the answer
- $12.38\%$ on the second day
- $2.43\%$ on the third day

So, activity drops down sharply by the third day. After that the decline is slow:

- $17.47\%$ of upvotes occur at least $30$ days after the answer was posted
- $7.00\%$ —  at least one year after
- $2.60\%$ —  at least two years after

---

The second part of answer follows the same format, but is restricted to the answers with total score at most $10$.  The pattern remains largely the same, but the tail is shorter.

- $66.22\%$ upvotes were cast within the first day of existence of the answer
- $11.59\%$ on the second day
- $2.18\%$ on the third day

Also,

- $13.60\%$ of upvotes occur at least $30$ days after the answer was posted
- $4.58\%$ —  at least one year after
- $1.40\%$ —  at least two years after

From [Upvotes on answers some days after the post](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/200430/upvotes-on-answers-some-days-after-the-post)

Comment: Nice! Can you distinguish between your two pairs of statistics? What I mean is that the 17%, 7%, 3% list reads as contradicting the 60%, 12%, 2$ list. Can you clarify?

Comment: @nayrb I added formatting to clarify. If you want to investigate the questions, feel free to fork the query, replacing p.PostTypeId = 2  with p.PostTypeId = 1.

Comment: Awesome. It is late here and I realized I was just confused. Accepted.

Comment: The implication from this seems to me that the reputation maximizing strategy is to answer often.